# using SD card as system memory

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

I am using an old system, but i recently upgraded my HDD to SSHD (2tb) and I wanted to dual boot Ubuntu with windows 10. But at the time of installation, I always get the error of adding an EFI partition. As having the windows 10 installed i have used three partitions { Sys.reserved, C drive (250gb), D drive (1.5tb) }. Now I can make one more primary or two logical partitions. So I was wondering that can I use an SD Card for my EFI partition, rather than squeezing up all in my main disk.
 If no, then do give me a short summary of the reason.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Maybve there's a better solution. Please run _lsblk | grep -v  'loop'|'tempfs'  && df -h | grep -v 'loop'|'tempfs'_ highlight and copy the text, return here, click [edit], and paste the results into your quesiton.

Comment: An EFI partition is usually very small,  about 100 to 300 MBs.  If you really need that small space, you probably could use an external hard drive for data.  You said old, so can it use EFI or only legacy?  Also both OSs should be the same way booted, UEFI or legacy

Comment: After reading question over, seems like you are using MBR partitions limited to 4.  If not much important data might recommend changing to GPT partitions.  Can have as many partitions as you like, but probably need to re install both OSs.

Comment: @crip659 Until the OP replies with the data requested, that's speculation; perhaps accurate, perhaps not.

Answer (score 1):

I strongly recommend against.

1) The access speed is significantly slower, as a disk speed test will show you.

2) It's *much* more likely to fail, both by accident and by its design. I've popped SD cards out of my Thinkpad by accident multiple times. Also, the IC in the SD card is much more likely to fail, for its design is nowhere near as durable, both physically, and electronically.